# Checking if data exist in sqlite-net before inserting them to database

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

Im making an Xamarin.Android application that will use "templates" , template is this:

```
[Table("Templates")]
    public class Template
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Category { get; set; }
        //[TextBlob("imagesBlobbed")]
        [OneToMany, Unique]
        public List<TemplateImage> TemplateImages { get; set; }
        public string ImagesHash { get; set; }
        //public string imagesBlobbed { get; set; }
    }
    [Table("TemplateImages")]
    public class TemplateImage
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Category { get; set; }
        public string ImagesHash { get; set; }
        public int Image { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(typeof(Template))]
        public int TemplateId { get; set; }
    }
```

i want all the TemplateImages objects to be unique in my database, the attribute **Unique** doesnt do anything, cause i guess because TemplateImage table has an auto increment Id will always be unique, no matter if the Image or ImageHash is the same in 2 records.

I was thinking then how else i can be sure that **TemplateImages** will be unique (**Notice**: when i say unique i mean that there isn't any other **List** that have the exact **Image** for every **TemplateImage**, in the same order).

Also i was using the ResourceID of the images, as image, which is wrong cause they might change on every new compiled app update.

So i decided to make a hash md5 from the images. They only way that i have find to load resource images (my images are **vector .xml** files) in **Xamarin.Android** is by converting the resource to bitmap, and then convert the bitmap to byte, and then the byte to md5.

And also i should have a hash string for the template item too. so im creating an md5 hash for the template by combining all the byte[] of the images into one and then hasing that.

I create this crazy code for this job:

```
        public static string GetMD5Hash(byte[] content)
        {
            using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
            {
                byte[] computedHash = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(BitConverter.ToString(content).Replace("-", "")));
                return new System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001.SoapHexBinary(computedHash).ToString();
            }
        }

        private static SQLiteConnection instance;
        public static SQLiteConnection db()
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "TemplatesData.db"));

            return instance;
        }
        public static void CloseConnection()
        {
            if (instance != null)
            {
                instance.Close();
                instance.Dispose();
                instance = null;
            }
        }

    }
    public class TemplateDB
    {
        public static byte[] ConcatByteList(List<byte[]> list)
        {
            return list
                .SelectMany(a => a)
                .ToArray();
        }

        public static Bitmap GetBitmapFromVectorDrawable(Context context, int drawableId)
        {
            Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(context, drawableId);
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
            {
                drawable = (DrawableCompat.Wrap(drawable)).Mutate();
            }

            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(drawable.IntrinsicWidth,
                    drawable.IntrinsicWidth, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            drawable.SetBounds(0, 0, canvas.Width, canvas.Height);
            drawable.Draw(canvas);

            return bitmap;
        }

        public byte[] DrawableToByteArray(int resourceId)
        {
            var context = AppState.ApplicationState;
            using (var bitmap = GetBitmapFromVectorDrawable(context, resourceId))
            {
                int size = bitmap.ByteCount;
                byte[] byteArray = new byte[size];
                ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.Allocate(size);
                bitmap.CopyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);
                byteBuffer.Rewind();
                byteBuffer.Get(byteArray);
                return byteArray;
            }
        }
        public static void AddTemplate(int category, List<int> images)
        {
            var templateDB = new TemplateDB();
            var imageByteList = new List<byte[]>();

            foreach (int image in images)
            {
                imageByteList.Add(templateDB.DrawableToByteArray(image));
            }
            var tmpl = new Template()
            {
                Category = category,
            };
            var img1 = new TemplateImage()
            {
                Category = category,
                Image = images[0],
                ImagesHash = DatabaseHelper.GetMD5Hash(imageByteList[0]),
            };
            var img2 = new TemplateImage()
            {
                Category = category,
                Image = images[1],
                ImagesHash = DatabaseHelper.GetMD5Hash(imageByteList[1]),
            };
            var img3 = new TemplateImage()
            {
                Category = category,
                Image = images[2],
                ImagesHash = DatabaseHelper.GetMD5Hash(imageByteList[2]),
            };
            var img4 = new TemplateImage()
            {
                Category = category,
                Image = images[3],
                ImagesHash = DatabaseHelper.GetMD5Hash(imageByteList[3]),
            };
            var img5 = new TemplateImage()
            {
                Category = category,
                Image = images[4],
                ImagesHash = DatabaseHelper.GetMD5Hash(imageByteList[4]),
            };
            tmpl.TemplateImages = new List<TemplateImage>() { img1, img2, img3, img4, img5 };
            tmpl.ImagesHash = DatabaseHelper.GetMD5Hash(ConcatByteList(imageByteList));
            var result = DatabaseHelper.db().Query<TemplateImage>("Select * from Templates where ImagesHash=?", tmpl.ImagesHash);
            if (result.Count == 0)
            {
            DatabaseHelper.db().InsertAll(tmpl.TemplateImages);
            DatabaseHelper.db().Insert(tmpl);
            DatabaseHelper.db().UpdateWithChildren(tmpl);
            }
        }
```

Which all of a sudden, gives out of memory exception.

After thinking for a while that i should stop programming and start belly dancing, i think that since im giving in sqlite **AddTemplate** function a list of **ResourceIds** that i have to manually create (can't avoid it), then why not to give them my own string hash code and compare that to find if a record exist?

What is the correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, i was thinking to use **guid** as extra **id fields** and add the parameter unique,in that case i could be sure which templates have been inserted, but i decided to use **transactions**. With transactions i can know that all my data is created or none and also save the creation into a variable in **SharedPreferences** and avoid recreating or even checking if the database exist.

For checking if the data is correctly updated and no recreation is needed i used this code:

```
public bool FirstRun { get; set; } = true;
public int DatabaseCreatedVersionOf { get; set; } = -1;

public override void OnCreate()
{
    base.OnCreate();
}

public void UpdateDatabaseCreatedVersion()
{
    DatabaseCreatedVersionOf = Preferences.Get(Settings.DatabaseCreatedVersionOfKey,
       Settings.DatabaseCreatedVersionOfDefault);
}

public void CreateTemplateDB()
{
    UpdateDatabaseCreatedVersion();
    if (DatabaseCreatedVersionOf == -1)
        TemplateDB.CreateDB();
    FirstRun = false;
}
public Template GetTemplateById(int id)
{
    if (FirstRun)
    {
        CreateTemplateDB();
        FirstRun = false;
    }

    return TemplateDB.GetTemplate(id);
}
public List<Template> GetAllTemplates()
{
    if (FirstRun)
    {
        CreateTemplateDB();
        FirstRun = false;
    }

    return TemplateDB.GetAllTemplates();
}
```

Now all i have to do is call **GetTemplateById** or **GetAllTemplates** and if any creation is required, it will happen.

Comment: It seems that you have solved your issue by yourself, please remember to mark your reply as answer, it is beneficial to other community members who face the same issue, thanks.

Comment: thanks, i will but should i wait first to see if more answers come?